# get last child when using Flex order Css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am not able to detect last child when using flex order to rearrange divs.
since I have arranged order of CSS with Order. its still getting the last child as per dom tree. items divs are dynamic. so we cant use nth-child.
how should I get the last child when rearranged with order. There can be multiple items that need to be shown on top. I need CSS or js based solution.
my code

```
    <div class="mainWrap">
     <div class="item">first</div>
     <div class="item">second</div>
     <div class="item orderFirst">third</div>
     <div class="item">fourth</div>
     <div class="item orderFirst">fifth</div>
     <div class="item">Six</div>
     <div class="item orderFirst">Seven</div>
    </div>

    <style>
    .mainWrap {display:flex; flex-direction: column;}
    .mainWrap .item {order:2; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc}
    .mainWrap .item:last-of-type {border-bottom:none;}
    .mainWrap .item.orderFirst {order:1;}
    </style>
```

Comment: if you're able to put a class on your last item, why not just add a class on your second to last item? otherwise you can use `:nth-last-child(2)`

Comment: I think you have a wrong in `.mainWrap .item {order:2}`. It applies `order: 2` to all of your first four items.

Comment: You can't with CSS. `last-child` is ALWAYS the DOM last child regardless of any **visual** changes made using CSS

Comment: It's certainly not necessary to add `order:2` to everything. Just add `order:-1` to the required "first" div.

Comment: well i cant use nth-child. i have a dynamic list. @Pete

Comment: @Paulie_D issue still the same. i am not able to detect the last child.

Comment: @MossawirAhmed it's `nth-last-child` unless you're saying that part of the dynamicness of the list is the order class will be added to a random div - if it's always on your last div then `nth-last-child(2)` will always get your second to last div no matter how many items are in your list.  You need to add all these extra caveats into your question

Comment: You CAN select the last child because that is what `last-child` does. What you CAN'T do is detect the last **visual** child with CSS. You need javascript.

Comment: @Paulie_D can you give a hint a little to detect the visual last child via js? i have modified the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're really determined to do it like this, you can use javascript to find the last element that doesn't have the `orderFirst` class and style that. This does seem like a mis-use of the `order` property, though.

```js
const mainWrap = document.querySelector(".mainWrap");

const children = [...mainWrap.children];
const ordered = children.filter((c) => !c.classList.contains("orderFirst"));

const last = ordered.pop();
last.style.setProperty("border-bottom", "none");
```

```css
.mainWrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  order: 2;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}

.item.orderFirst {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainWrap">
  <div class="item">first</div>
  <div class="item">second</div>
  <div class="item orderFirst">third</div>
  <div class="item">fourth</div>
  <div class="item orderFirst">fifth</div>
  <div class="item">Six</div>
  <div class="item orderFirst">Seven</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reverse your `border`s like this:

```
.item {
  order: 2; // this seems wrong by the way
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc; // set the TOP border on every .item
}

.item.orderFirst {
  order: 1;
  border-top: none; // unset it for the (visually) first element
}
```

If your actual use-case is as simple as the example, this should give you what you want.

Comment: i can't do that. since orderFirst class is added to items class when it detect specific type of item. that class can be found on top or at the end.

Answer (score -1):

You mean to delete the border of the last visible element and not the last element of the div container mainWrap, right?

```css
.mainWrap {display:flex; flex-direction: column;}
.mainWrap > div { order:2; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc }
.mainWrap > div:nth-last-child(2) { border-bottom:none; }
.mainWrap > div:last-child { order:1; background: red;}
```

```html
 <div class="mainWrap">
     <div class="item">first</div>
     <div class="item">second</div>
     <div class="item">third</div>
     <div class="item">fourth</div>
     <div class="item orderFirst">fifth</div>
 </div>
```